# Select Multiple content picker in Umbraco marco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am using umbraco 7.4.3.
In Macro I want to select multiple Node from Content Picker. can we have Multi node tree view in Macro.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom macro pickers I believe. You could create your own that allows you to pick multiple items of content? You could also try setting the multi node picker as allowed as a parameter editor by setting the "isParameterEditor" value to true in the DataType config,as shown here: http://www.nibble.be/?p=349

Answer (score 0):

Nope, AFAIK the macro parameter types are limited to what is out of the box. But have you looked at the Nested Content package? That might help you solve your problem.